# Using Uploadify with big files (2GB+)

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, uploadify

I'm using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to create a file uploader to Amazon S3. I need it to work on files up to 2GB, and show an error if the file is bigger than that. I don't have a finer file granulation, but for a 3.5GB file it works correctly (i.e. shows the error), and for a 10GB file it doesn't even want to select it or trigger *any* event. (The file open dialog .closes and nothing happens, as if the user didn't select the file in the first place).

Is there a bug in the Uploadify code and if it is, how can I make it work?